# keyframe animation does not start

Tags: html, css, animation

i was making my project, but when i added a keyframe from animation this does not work. for not working i means does not start. The result that i want is like that (sorry for the bad quality):
[image]

I have just tryed to add relative position, change animation name or add different style, but the problem is other, the animation does not start. This is the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/zoL2w1fk/

```
    <div id="shop">
    <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/450ec7c827a3e004f38d9b70220a2e46.png" id="shop-image">
</div>

    -webkit-keyframes shopanimation {

    from 0% {
        -ms-transform: rotate(10deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotate(10deg);
    }
    to 100% {
        -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotate(-10deg);
    }
}
@keyframes shopanimation {
    from 0% {
        -ms-transform: rotate(10deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotate(10deg);
    }
    to 100% {
        -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotate(-10deg);

    }
}
div#shop {
    background-color:#33373f;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}
div#shop img {
    cursor:pointer;
    /*TEST*/
    -webkit-animation: shopanimation 1s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
    -moz-animation:    shopanimation 1s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
    -o-animation:      shopanimation 1s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
    animation:         shopanimation 1s infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}
div#shop:hover > img {
    -webkit-animation: shopanimation 1s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
    -moz-animation:    shopanimation 1s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
    -o-animation:      shopanimation 1s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
    animation:         shopanimation 1s infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}
```

Thank you in advice for spending your time form me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a small syntactical error in your keyframe declarations - no need to write `from` and `to`, so just remove them:

```css
-webkit-keyframes shopanimation {
    0% {
        -ms-transform: rotate(10deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotate(10deg);
    }
    100% {
        -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotate(-10deg);
    }
}
@keyframes shopanimation {
    0% {
        -ms-transform: rotate(10deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotate(10deg);
    }
    100% {
        -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotate(-10deg);

    }
}
```

Here's an [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zoL2w1fk/1/). Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could help you overcome this problem.

Comment: @terzi_matte Just on a side note, don't forget to mark this answer as "accepted" (click the grey check mark next to it) when you get the chance - this way, people can see that the question has been successfully solved.